# Почему не рендерится? Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Есть разметка:

```
<div id="consturctor">
  <cb-top-line>
    <cb-step class="cb-step--current" id="cb-step1" number="1" title="Изображение">
    </cb-step>
    <cb-step id="cb-step2" number="2" title="Рама">
    </cb-step>
    <cb-step id="cb-step3" number="3" title="Заголовок">
    </cb-step>
    <cb-step id="cb-step4" number="4" title="Цвет отпечатков">
    </cb-step>
  </cb-top-line>
</div>
```

Вот сами компоненты:

```
Vue.component('cb-top-line', {
    template: '<div class="cb-top-line"></div>'
})

Vue.component('cb-step', {
    props: ['number', 'title'],
    template: '<div class="cb-step"> \
                    <p> \
                        <span>{{ number }}</span> \
                        {{ title }}\
                    </p> \
               </div>'
})

let vm = new Vue({
    el: '#constructor'
})
```

В результате отображается пустой cb-top-line, без cb-step внутри.

Comment: А откуда они там внутрях возьмутся? В шаблоне то их нету

Comment: а как тогда правильно записать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все рендерится. Вы в `index` написали разметку, `vue` находит элемент `cb-top-line`, он знает что это `component`. В результате он берет разметку которую вы написали в этом компоненте и вставляет ее. У вас написано

```
template: '<div class="cb-top-line"></div>'
```

Вот он и отображается пустой `cb-top-line`. Для вызова другого компонента, напишите вызов этого компонента в компоненте `cb-top-line`. 
Вот так это должно работать.

```
 Vue.component('cb-top-line', {
        template: '\
                   <div class="cb-top-line">\
                     <cb-step class="cb-step--current" id="cb-step1" number="1" title="Изображение">\
                     </cb-step>\
                     <cb-step id="cb-step2" number="2" title="Рама">\
                     </cb-step>\
                     <cb-step id="cb-step3" number="3" title="Заголовок">\
                     </cb-step>\
                     <cb-step id="cb-step4" number="4" title="Цвет отпечатков">\
                     </cb-step>\
                   </div>\
                 '

    })
```